# Distance between 2 duplicate number in an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to calculate distance between 2 duplicate numbers in an array using JavaScript ex:

```
    ["2","3","4","2"] => 3 (2 is a duplicate number)
    ["1","4","5","5"] => 1 (5 is a duplicate number)
    ["1","4","5","9","4"] => 3 (4 is a duplicate number)
```

Comment: guarantee only one duplicate or?

Comment: if you can do 2 situations. that'd be great

Comment: Did you give it a shot yourself? Or are you just looking for the answer. It is a lot nicer if you would post some code trying it yourself.

Comment: I only know using loop for it but I dont know how.

Comment: @tamnguyen, what distance value should I get if there's three or more duplicates in array, e.g. `["2","3","4","2","3","5","6","2"]` ?

Comment: let assume minimum distance. It would be ["2"] => 3; ["3"] => 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you will not have more than two occurrences of any given value in your array, we can take the following steps:-

1. Traverse the array items and get all the indexes of each item,
2. Add the item to an `encountered` array, that will help you to identify if the item has already been searched for,
3. If the item has 2 occurrences, get the difference between the indexes and that will be your number of steps.

In Javascript, the following code will do the same for you.

```js
var temp = [2,3,4,2,5,4,1,3];
var encountered = [];

//This function gets you all the indexes of `val` inside `arr` array.
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
  var indexes = [], i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i] === val)
      indexes.push(i);
  return indexes;
}

for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++) {
    if(encountered[temp[i]]) continue; 
    else {
        var indexes = getAllIndexes(temp, temp[i]);
        encountered[temp[i]] = true;
        if(indexes.length>1) {
            var steps = indexes[1]-indexes[0];
            $('.container').append('Duplicate item: '+temp[i]+' steps: '+ steps+'<br/>');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Working JSFiddle here -> https://jsfiddle.net/dmnuwas5/

Comment: @tamnguyen You are welcome! Please accept if this helped. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this pseudo-code will put you on the right path:

```
values = original array
distances = {}
firstIndex = {}

loop over values with index i {
  item = values[i]
  if firstIndex[item] >= 0 { // this is important because the first index could be 0
    if item does not exist in distances object { // This would be different if you are going for max distance instead of min distance in the case of multiple of the same item
      distances[item] = i - firstIndex[item]
    }
  } else {
    firstIndex[item] = i
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal for multiple occurrence of the same item and the calculating of an at least minimal distance.

```js
function getDistance(array) {
    var o = {}, r = {};
    array.forEach(function (a, i) {
        o[a] = o[a] || [];
        o[a].push(i);
    });
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (o[k].length > 1) {
            r[k] = Math.min.apply(null, o[k].reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
                i && r.push(a - aa[i - 1]);
                return r;
            }, []));
        }
    });
    return r;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getDistance([2,3,4,2,5,4,1,3]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getDistance(["2", "3", "4", "2", "3", "5", "6", "2"]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example that satisfies your requirements. It returns an object with the duplicate number as the key, and the distance as value.

```
function sift(arr) {
  for (var i =  0, l = arr.length, out = {}; i < l; i++) {
    var key = arr.shift();
    var index = arr.indexOf(key);
    if (index > -1 && !out[key]) out[key] = index + 1;
  }
  return out;
}

sift(["2","3","4","2"]); // { 2: 3 }
sift(["1","4","5","5"]); // { 5: 1 }
sift(["1","4","5","9","4"]); // { 4: 3 }
sift(["2","3","4","2","3","5","6","2"]); // { 2: 3, 3: 3 }
sift(["6","2","3","4","2","3","5","6","2"]); // { 2: 3, 3: 3, 6: 7 }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xnfkjxgb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Java code for finding distance between duplicate elements. If there are multiple duplicate elements, this will return the minimum of the distances between the duplicate element pairs. Also, assumes that the duplicate elements occur twice (not more than twice)

Time Complexity: O(n)

Space Complexity: O(n)

```
public int minDuplicateDistance(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> dups = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        if (dups.containsKey(arr[x])) {
            int index = dups.get(arr[x]);
            int distance = x - index;
            minDistance = minDistance > distance ? distance : minDistance;
        } else {
            dups.put(arr[x], x);
        }
    }
    return minDistance;
}
```